# How to use a token set by DeviseTokenAuth in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a Rails web app which uses mongoid and Devise for user authentication. I'd like to add API functionality for use with an iOS app, so I've added the devise_token_auth gem (I had to tweak it a bit to get it to work with mongoid, but it seems to be working correctly). Now I'm looking for some help with how to use the tokens which devise_token_auth adds to the User records.

I'm using a ruby script for testing which looks like this:

```
require 'httparty'

base_uri = "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/sign_in"
uri = URI.parse(base_uri)

email = "test@example.com"
password = "abc123"

payload = {email: email, password: password }
response = HTTParty.post(base_uri, :body => payload)

puts "Response: #{response.message}"
puts "Response: #{response.body}"
```

When I execute this script, a new field is added to the database record for the user with email test@example.com, so it looks like this:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5571db594169727489000000"),
"email" : "test@example.com",
"encrypted_password" : "$2a$10$9cgGVPYuaW2Bb1y",
"name" : "Test User",
"updated_at" : ISODate("2015-10-09T20:34:09.711Z"),
"created_at" : ISODate("2015-06-05T17:24:41.734Z"),
"tokens" : {
    "J0eQp5hL8HfYvigrJOUQ" : {
        "token" : "$2a$10$xxJ84bQGH93zpMtI0W",
        "expiry" : 1445632449
    }
},
"uid" : "abcxyz"
```

All well and good.  The response body contains all the above user data except the password field and the token field. Now what I can't figure out from the documentation is how to use this new token for subsequent API calls. The token information is not returned in the response body.

The devise_token_auth documentation states: "The authentication headers required for each request will be available in the response from the previous request." Here's what I see in the response, in addition to the user record information:

```
@response=#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>, @headers={"x-frame-options"=>["SAMEORIGIN"], "x-xss-protection"=>["1; mode=block"], "x-content-type-options"=>["nosniff"], "content-type"=>["application/json; charset=utf-8"], "etag"=>["W/\"2258296e307edb117bc9e81b83fb71a8\""], "cache-control"=>["max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"], "x-request-id"=>["26f956cd-9924-42e0-bbfa-5878a3651339"], "x-runtime"=>["0.424290"], "connection"=>["close"], "transfer-encoding"=>["chunked"]}>
```

How can I use that information to make additional requests?

My controller code looks like this:

```
class Api::V1::ApiCommentsController < ApplicationController

  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index    


    render json: {
      data: {
        message: "Welcome, #{current_user.name}!"
      }
    }, status: 200

  end
end
```

I'd like to test with a script similar to the one I listed above, along these lines:

```
require 'httparty'

uid = "123"

base_uri = "http://localhost:3000/comments_api"
uri = URI.parse(base_uri)

payload = {"uid" => uid, "access-token" => "???" }

response = HTTParty.get(base_uri, headers: payload)

puts "Response: #{response.message}"
puts "Response: #{response.body}"
```

I don't know what should go in the access-token field, or if any additional headers are required to validate the user. Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

In the payload you will need uid, access-token and client, you find these 3 values in the response headers:
[image: response headers]